# Finding emails filtered by a blacklist

Tags: postfix, blacklist

my postfix is configured to forward emails from a domain to an icloud.com email. Unfortunately, my server landed in one of the blacklists that icloud is using and now my client is not receiving his emails. I'll find a way to go around that, but I am wondering if there is any way to retrieve all these emails that were filtered.
**/var/lib/postfix** doesn't contain anything interesting.
**/var/lib/mail** only has local accounts.
If it's not there by default, what would be a way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

The sending mailserver, your postfix, will have either recorded that the messages were received by the recipients mail server and then there is nothing you can do. You  can’t tell if they were placed into the recipients inbox, junk folder or silently discarded there.

Alternatively  the recipients mail server rejected the messages during the SMTP transaction. Then depending on the nature of the rejection your mailserver will have queued the message for later delivery or triggered a bounce message with a delivery error to the sender. You should be able to tell from your logs.